# ARToolKit on ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, glut, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I have been trying to setup ARToolkit on my UBUNTU 11.10 pc.The problem i am facing it that it requires GLUT/OpenGL lib and SDK and i am not able to figure out how to do that.

How can I set up ARToolKit on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`